# How to convert getdate() stored as varchar to date

Tags: sql-server, database-design, stored-procedures, datetime, string

I have stored 'getdate()' as text in one of my column in a table. (It's a complicated scenario ,how I saved it)
Now when I select the field what I am getting is getdate() instead of the date . How can I convert this to date time.

I am adding a sample code to understand this

```
declare @a varchar(20)='getdate()'

select convert(datetime,@a)
```

This results in conversion error. How can I convert this to date?

Comment: You can't convert it to a date, you never saved the date in the first place. The data simply isn't there. You can calculate a *new* date as the answers show.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case statement.

```
declare @a varchar(20)='getdate()';
select case when @a = 'getdate()' then getdate() end;
```

Comment: Thanks @mikael 

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL for this, however it is very prone to SQL Injection.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(20) = 'getdate()';

EXEC ('SELECT convert(datetime,' + @a + ')');
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Hard coded like Mikael Eriksson proposed.

Comment: can you help me with this ?  https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/324870/264601